# Mnemonics but for Public addresses

Tags: address

Are there any implemented ways for turning addresses into human-readable word(s)? If not, why? I.e., are there any known technological issues in implementing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any implemented ways for turning addresses into human-readable word(s)?

No

> If not, why?

Because, copy-pasting works and no one has proposed a method for something that no one I'm aware of has needed.

> I.e., are there any known technological issues in implementing this?

No

Comment: It might be worth mentioning checksums and QR-codes both of which which also help avoid transcription errors and make addresses easier to use.